# Android Keyboard Handling Primer?

Tags: android, keyboard

I have an book that's supposed to teach everything about Android programming. Unfortunately that book is missing so much information on fundamental stuff, it's not even funny. Its index doesn't even include an entry for onKeyDown()...

Can you recommend a resource that can teach a n00b like me how to handle keyboard events and possibly even understand how they work?

For example, how do I hook a function that I wrote to a key combination?

Does "key combination" exist in touchscreen-only Android devices?

Comment: I can't answer all your questions (am a beginner myself) but perhaps this official KeyEvent overview could help? http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html

Comment: You may find the following helpful as well: http://www.kandroid.org/android_pdk/keymaps_keyboard_input.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure you can have key combinations in Android, as there are devices that only have single touch support (and no keyboards). Of course, there could have been changes. You may find some info in the [android hardware compatibility reference](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBYQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fsource.android.com%2Fcompatibility%2Fandroid-2.3-cdd.pdf&ei=YRR0TYG_KMW7hAfYsYmcDQ&usg=AFQjCNG3bFT0vkfsHZFvVVNtb5aweSiVIg&sig2=xCL6ePoCK48u8hBf8NS9iA).

For guidance you may look at the [UI Events guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/ui-events.html) for Android. Also, you may try searching Google, or StackOverflow, as there are many helpful guides and tutorials for beginners. You just have to dig them out.